# adding CORS policy causes fetch POST from my react project to fail

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

When I add and configure a CORS policy to my program.cs, my fetch POST from my react project fail. If I add a policy to allow any origin/any method/any header, my post succeeds.

I see my browser makes a pre-fetch request for OPTIONS which includes the referrer of `myapp.mycompany.com` (not really but you get the idea). In my web api, my cors policy includes `http://*.mycompany.com` and `https://*.mycompany.com`. The server responds with 204 no content and does NOT contain the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, which I understand to be my problem.

I can't figure out what I have misconfigured here. This is deployed internally. I am using IIS 8.5 and ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

Any direction on what I may be missing would be appreciated. Thanks.

CORS Policy:

```
            builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
        {
            option.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy",
            policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins(
                    "http://localhost:3000",
                    "https://localhost:3000",
                    "http://*.mycompanydomain.com",
                    "https://*.mycompanydomain.com")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
```

Preflight / OPTIONS Response:

```
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2023 12:17:34 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.setisoriginallowedtoallowwildcardsubdomains?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @jub0bs - Thank you. This was what I missed and was the resolution. I now see Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response fromt he preflight and my post succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

As jub0bs suggested up above, I was missing the  SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains property on my policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.setisoriginallowedtoallowwildcardsubdomains?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Try add `http://172.23.40.24:80` to your origin policy. The Remote address should be the right origin.
[image]